# Python range function step size list assignment out of range error, simulating a brainteaser

Tags: python, range

A classic math brainteaser, problem statement taken from leetcode
"There are n bulbs that are initially off. You first turn on all the bulbs. Then, you turn off every second bulb. On the third round, you toggle every third bulb (turning on if it's off or turning off if it's on). For the ith round, you toggle every i bulb. For the nth round, you only toggle the last bulb. Find how many bulbs are on after n rounds."

I realize there is a concise solution to the problem itself but I want to simulate the bulb switching on/off problem. But as the step size increases I am running into list index out of range errors, how do I handle this error? I want the values to be toggled only if the index is still valid.

```python
 def bulbSwitch(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        bulbs= [0]*n
        step=0
        for i in range(n):
            step += 1
            for s in range(0, n, step):
                bulbs[s+i]=0 if bulbs[s]==1 else 1 #this line produces error
        print bulbs
```

Comment: Why `bulbs[s+i]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't want to start from bulbs[0] each time, when step size is 2, I want to start at bulbs[1], step size is 3, start at bulbs[2] and etc.

Comment: I get that, but why add the number of the current round?

Comment: If you think your logic is correct put that for loop under 
try:
    code
except IndexError:
    pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the issue is the `s+i` index. The maximum value for `s` in the loop is `n-1`, so if you add anything to it, you're going to run past the end of the list.

You said you want to start with `bulbs[1]` when `step` is 2, `bulbs[2]` when `step` is 3, etc. So just start your range there instead:

```
for step in range(1, n+1):  # this avoids separate `i` vs. `step` variables
    for s in range(step-1, n, step):  # start in the right place
        bulbs[s] = 0 if bulbs[s] == 1 else 1
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps this is easier? (Here I used a `+1` instead of a `-1`.)

```
for step in range(n):  # this avoids separate `i` vs. `step` variables
    for s in range(step, n, step+1):  # start in the right place
        bulbs[s] = 0 if bulbs[s] == 1 else 1
```

**EDIT 2**

Just making sure it works... I added a test (which passes):

```
import math

def bulb_switch(n):
    bulbs = [0] * n

    for step in range(n):  # this avoids separate `i` vs. `step` variables
        for s in range(step, n, step+1):  # start in the right place
            bulbs[s] = 0 if bulbs[s] == 1 else 1

    return sum(bulbs)

for i in range(1000):
    assert math.floor(math.sqrt(i)) == bulb_switch(i)
```

Comment: It works well and I learned how to use range( ) more properly now. The code returns the correct array of on/off bulbs, but is deemed too slow by leetcode OJ when n is large (9999).

Comment: FWIW, I tried to optimize this with `bulbs[s] ^= 1`, but it appears to be a little slower (but I just tested it with the bash time command, not a proper `timeit` test). I guess an `if` test and setting a list item to a constant is faster than doing arithmetic. Oh well. :)

Comment: @user53008 I assume leetcode passes large values on purpose to make sure that to pass the test you have to write the mathematical solution (which does not get slower as `n` increases).

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Yes I believe the intent is to rule-out an O(n^2) solution like this one